# How to run two functions signalR Hub?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I currently have a Message page which displays all the new messages which are sent to the user. These messages are stored in a database along with a `NewMessageCount`. if the user has one new message a small notification will get displayed next to the Message which is selected from `NewMessagecount`. I am using SignalR to achieve this and I'm very new to SignalR so do excuse me if I'm making a obvious mistake.

I have two function in the `Hub` which work fine because they filter and update correct fields. However my question is I can't seem get both of these functions to run one after another on the message page. I want when the user clicks on the message tab the `notifications.server.removeNotification();` to run

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;

        notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (totalNewMessages) {

            $('#NewMessages').text(totalNewMessages);
        };
        notifications.client.removeNotification = function (totalNewMessages) {
            $('.Message').click(function () {
                $('#NewMessages').text(totalNewMessages);
            });
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            notifications.server.sendNotifications();
            notifications.server.removeNotification(); //This is what i want to run on the click event?? But don't know how to
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
});           
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but as a side notice - move your `click` handler out of `removeNotification` callback - now it adds a new callback to click event each time `Clients.removeNotification` is called, which is not what you want I guess.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Sorry if I haven't made it clear. Similar to what SO has a notification system when a comment is made gets displayed at the top and when the user clicks on it, it then disappears. That's what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Add `click` handler inside your `hub.start` callback, like this: `... $('.Message').click(function () {  notifications.server.removeNotification(); }`. And `$('#NewMessages').text` will be updated in `client.recieveNotification` callback, as it is currently. Is this what you want?

Comment: You're invoking removeNotifications on the server, which likely doesn't exist. That's not right. You need to register the click handler once, it doesn't have anything to do with SignalR. So move it out of the `$.connection.hub.start` block.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Thanks, That's cleared it up for me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @IlyaLuzyanin comment I manage to solve the issue by adding the `click` handler  inside the `hub.start`

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
            notifications.server.sendNotifications();
            $('.removemessage').click(function () {
                notifications.server.removeNotifications();
            })
        });
```